# "Track active items in solution explorer" doesn't work

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.1

The option "Track active items in solution explorer" in visual studio doesn't seem to work.
I am using visual studio 2013 ultimate and Resharper 8.1.
I've tried un-checking and checking again, didn't work.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you give more details about what's not working?  What did you try, what did you expect, what did you get?

Comment: If "Track active items in solution explorer" option is turned on (Tools->options->Projects and solutions-> Track active items in solution explorer) every active document in the editor will be shown and selected in the solution explorer
(unless it's in an unopened folder in the solution explorer).
A restart solved the problem for now, however it's a recurring issue so it's still relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem. It's a bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800369/problem-with-track-active-item-in-solution-explorer-option

Comment: Accepted answer maybe?

Comment: The link is broken, @Ananth answers is a good workaround!

Comment: yeah, maybe, Microsoft links don't live forever {:-), but it's still or was a bug

Answer (score 5):

Faced this issue today . Tried deleting .vs directory and issue was fixed.

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, click on `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions`, then make sure the option `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` is `unchecked`.

In Visual Studio again, click on `Extensions -> Resharper -> Options -> Performance Guide`
and set the option `Don't track active item in Solution Explorer` to `Ignore`